# How to start Marquee text start from bottom of the screen?

Tags: html, marquee

Hello i am using **marquee**  to scroll from bottom to top.It working fine but it is starting from mid of the screen.But i need to start it from bottom.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<body bgcolor="#2E9AFE"> 

<marquee bgcolor="#2E9AFE" scrollamount="2" direction="up" loop="true"> 
<center> <font color="#ffffff"><strong> I AM HERE<br> 
                                        Vx.0<br><br> 
                                        DEVELOPER<br>
                                        xxxxxx<br><br>
                                        <br> CONTACT US<br>
                                        xxxxxx</strong></font></center></marquee>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're using some pretty outdated tags and attributes for one. Why is HTML5 tagged?

Comment: then suggest me new tags please

Answer (score 3):

Vertical Marquee using key-frames:

```css
.marquee {
  position: relative;
  animation: marquee 2s linear infinite;
  text-align:center;
  color:#ffffff;
}
@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    top: 10em
  }
  100% {
    top: -2em
  }
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#2E9AFE"> 
 <p class="marquee">
      I AM HERE<br> 
      Vx.0<br><br> 
      DEVELOPER<br>
      xxxxxx<br><br>
      <br> CONTACT US<br>
      xxxxxx
 </p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body bgcolor="#2E9AFE"> 
  <marquee style="background-color: #2E9AFE; bottom: 0; color: #ffffff; height: 100%; position: absolute; text-align: center;" scrollamount="2" direction="up" loop="true"> 
    <strong>I AM HERE<br/>Vx.0<br/><br/>DEVELOPER<br/>xxxxxx<br/><br/><br/>CONTACT US<br/>xxxxxx</strong>
  </marquee>
</body>
</html>
```

Please note, to my knowledge this is not valid HTML. To validate, check out [http://validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/). Also, there were two body tags (instead of one) and some other HTML that wasn't properly formatted, most of which I tried to address. If you're not yet familiar with CSS, just know that it's your friend. (In other words, you'd probably be doing yourself a favor if the next thing you learned was CSS. It makes life much easier.)

Screenshot from my computer:
[image: Marquee preview]

Hope that helps... :)

Comment: mmm.. It's starting from Bottom but ends at MID of the screen and not aligned center of the screen. I want to scroll text like end titles of the movie START FROM BOTTOM OF THE SCREEN AND ENDS AT TOP OF THE SCREEN AND ALIGN CENTER OF THE SCREEN.

Comment: Yes it's working f9 in Mozilla Firefox.But in Google Chrome it is coming like as i mentioned in above comment.And same in my Android APP also.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use `width="500"` `height="400"` in the `<marquee>` tag

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body bgcolor="#2E9AFE">

  <marquee bgcolor="#2E9AFE" width="500" height="400" scrollamount="2" direction="up" loop="true">
    <center>
      <font color="#ffffff"><strong> I AM HERE<br> 
                                        Vx.0<br><br> 
                                        DEVELOPER<br>
                                        xxxxxx<br><br>
                                        <br> CONTACT US<br>
                                        xxxxxx</strong></font>
    </center>
  </marquee>



</body>

</html>
```